# Will rendering random items in list affect SEO?

Tags: seo, products, random

On my product details page, there is a section for related products (or similar products) and I only display 4 items in this list, but I want to render random items every time I open the details page, so visitors see various items constantly.

Will this affect my website ranking from an SEO perspective?

Comment: Are these "random items" to be instead of the "related products" list - as this seems to imply? Because that would probably be a bad idea. But if it's "as well as" then it probably won't make any difference in terms of SEO, providing your site is already crawlable.

Comment: I have like 10-12 related products and the list only displays 4 items, so I want to show all of the items in a random way not just only the first 4 items!!, and yes they are labeled as related products.